# how to use set functions of data table inside an environment

Tags: r, data.table

My task is to assign column names and group id to data inside an environment.

I have two cases below. The first one has data created using `data.frame()` and in case-2, the data is created using `data.table()`.

The first case is showing error, but the second one works perfectly well. Why is the error occurring in case-1, but not in case-2? Is there a better way to use set functions of `data.table` inside an environment?

```
library('data.table')
```

**Case 1:**

```
my_env <- new.env()
my_env$d1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
my_env$d2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
my_env$d3 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)

# set column names and value as group id
for(i in ls(my_env)){
  with(my_env, setDT(get(i))) # convert to data table by reference
  with(my_env, setnames( x = get(i), c('x', 'y')))  # assign column name by reference
  with(my_env, set( x = get(i), j = 'group', value = '0_0')) # assign group column with a value
}
```

Error:

> ```
>  Error in set(x = get(i), j = "group", value = "0_0") : 
>   Internal error, please report (including result of sessionInfo()) to datatable-help: oldtncol (0) < oldncol (2) but tl of
>   class is marked.
> ```

**Case 2:**

```
my_env2 <- new.env()
my_env2$d1 <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
my_env2$d2 <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
my_env2$d3 <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)

# set column names and value as group id
for(i in ls(my_env2)){
  # with(my_env, setDT(get(i))) # convert to data table by reference
  with(my_env2, setnames( x = get(i), c('x', 'y')))  # assign column name by reference
  with(my_env2, set( x = get(i), j = 'group', value = '0_0')) # assign group column with a value
}
```

Session Information

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Comment: Don't think it's related to environments. You can repro this with `setDT(get("mtcars")) ; set(x = get("mtcars"), j = "test", value = 1)`. It's probably has something to do with `get`. I'm also not sure how does `setDT(get("mtcars"))` even works as it doesn't assign `attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>` as a normal `setDT` will do (not to mention that just `setDT(mtcars)` won't work in this case). Either way, I think you should follow the advice of the error and file a bug report on GH

Comment: @DavidArenburg `setDT(get("mtcars"))` works because it is called inside `with()` in my example, I guess

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `setDT(get("mtcars"))` works inside global environment too

Comment: I was referring  to the usage of `with()` function, which provides a separate environment for the object, so calling `with(my_env, setDT(get(i)))` will work.

Comment: Again, it doesn't look environment related, as we can repro this like in my first comment.

Comment: I think it is because `setDT` uses `assign` to make the in-place replacement but doesn't cover this input case, so that step doesn't go through. If it's passed as a symbol it works, though `ex = quote(with(my_env, {setDT(d1); set(d1, j = "group", v = "0_0")})); eval(ex); my_env$d1` Fwiw, besides `get("d1")` it also fails with `my_env[["d1"]]`.

Comment: So I found the error [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/src/assign.c/#L449). The problem seem to be when running `setDT(get(i))` there is no memory allocated (no `attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>`), hence `truelength` returns zero and hence the error. Can be rpeorduced with `dt <- data.frame(a = 1) ; setDT(get("dt")) ; str(dt) ; truelength(dt) ; setDT(dt) ; str(dt) ; truelength(dt) `

Comment: I prefer you would open an issue on GH and once it got fixed, Arun/Matt/Jan will post a solution after a fix

Comment: For reference issue link https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2788

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just changed the way to create the group column and it worked fine to me. I also used `names()` instead of `ls()`:

```
# set column names and value as group id
for(i in names(my_env)){
  with(my_env, setnames( x = my_env[[i]], c('x', 'y')))  # assign column name by reference
  my_env[[i]][,"group"] <- "0_0" # assign group column with a value
}
```